# Unable to run python coblox script from cronjob

Tags: python, roblox

errors

```
    cmd:  python roblox-script.py model.fbx
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\Desktop\aws-vdm\roblox-script.py", line 43, in <module>
        insX, insY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('name-input.png', confidence=0.9)
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 175, in wrapper
        return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyautogui\__init__.py", line 207, in locateCenterOnScreen
        return pyscreeze.locateCenterOnScreen(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 413, in locateCenterOnScreen
        coords = locateOnScreen(image, **kwargs)
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 372, in locateOnScreen
        screenshotIm = screenshot(region=None) # the locateAll() function must handle cropping to return accurate coordinates, so don't pass a region here.
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 145, in wrapper
        return wrappedFunction(*args, **kwargs)
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pyscreeze\__init__.py", line 457, in _screenshot_win32
        im = ImageGrab.grab()
    File "D:\Users\soubhagya\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\PIL\ImageGrab.py", line 46, in grab
        offset, size, data = Image.core.grabscreen_win32(
    OSError: screen grab failed
```

Python code

```
    import pyautogui
    import time
    import tkinter as tk
    import random, string
    import requests


    root = tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()

    # print("mode_name", sys.argv[1])


    def randomword(length):
    letters = string.ascii_lowercase
    return ''.join(random.choice(letters) for i in range(length))

    gameName = randomword(10)

    screenWidth, screenHeight = pyautogui.size()
    currentMouseX, currentMouseY = pyautogui.position()
    pyautogui.FAILSAFE=False


    print('trying to open roblox studio...')
    pyautogui.moveTo(41, 224, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad, )
    pyautogui.doubleClick()

    print('waiting for roblox to open')
    time.sleep(15)

    print('opening boilerplate...')
    pyautogui.moveTo(410, 148, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.doubleClick()
    time.sleep(15)

    print('publish the sh...')

    pyautogui.hotkey('alt', 'p')
    time.sleep(5)

    print('Add name...', gameName)
    insX, insY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('name-input.png', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(insX, insY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.doubleClick()
    time.sleep(3)
    pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'a')
    pyautogui.press('backspace')
    pyautogui.typewrite(gameName)
    time.sleep(15)

    print('Click create...')
    crtX, crtY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('create-btn.PNG', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(crtX, crtY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(15)

    print('Set permissions...')
    shrX, shrY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('share-btn.PNG', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(shrX, shrY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(3)

    shrX, shrY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('game-settings.png', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(shrX, shrY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    shrX, shrY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('permission.PNG', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(shrX, shrY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    shrX, shrY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('save-btn.PNG', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(shrX, shrY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(10)

    shrX, shrY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('share-btn.PNG', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(shrX, shrY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(3)

    shrX, shrY = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen('copy-btn.png', confidence=0.9)
    pyautogui.moveTo(shrX, shrY, duration=2, tween=pyautogui.easeInOutQuad)
    pyautogui.click()
    time.sleep(3)
```

I have written one script which will automaticall open roblox
application and run the model

When i run the script manually it is working fine when i run using cronjob
It is giving avove error.

please take a look.

It is giving OS error maybe some permission issue or something.
Please check

Comment: Don't cronjobs run in a unix environment? The error is an operating system error. Can you use win32 APIs in a unix environment?

Comment: No. Linux won't work. Because roblox works only in windows